# HTTPS через TCP (80 порт) php

Tags: php, http, ssl, https, tcp

Я не собираюсь так делать но стало интересно.
Будут ли ошибки если есть статус https,  но я буду передавать данные через TCP подключаясь к 80 порту.

Ну например так :

```
if($data_url['scheme'] == 'https'){
fsockopen("tcp://$data_url[host]" , 80)
}
```

HTTPS вроде как использует TCP , просто добавляется SSL шифрование.

Если так сделать ,то будут какие-либо ошибки? Мне просто кажется что ошибок быть не должно,просто данные будут передаваться без шифрования.

Comment: проще проверить, чем спрашивать

Answer (score 0):

Если вы подключитесь через SSL на порт 80, где у вас HTTPS, ошибок не будет. Ошибка будет если вы будете слать обычный HTTP запрос на этот порт без ДО установки зашифрованного соединения. У каждого протокола есть правила общения, и если их нарушать то будут ошибки.